# Canvas using high CPU in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas

I am using a Codepen demo but after checking the CPU usage in chrome, it is using approx 100% of CPU. After trying hard, I am not able to figure out the problem as I am not an expert in javascript and canvas. What modifications do I need to make it use less CPU.
[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/piyushwalia/pen/JxMbMM)
As per my understanding, the problem is in animating particles or maybe I am wrong.

```js
// Global Animation Setting
window.requestAnimFrame = 
  window.requestAnimationFrame ||
  window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
  window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
  window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
  window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
  function(callback) {
    window.setTimeout(callback, 1000/60);
};

// Global Canvas Setting
var canvas = document.getElementById('particle');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;


// Particles Around the Parent
function Particle(x, y, distance) {
  this.angle = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
  this.radius = Math.random() ; 
  this.opacity =  (Math.random()*5 + 2)/10;
  this.distance = (1/this.opacity)*distance;
  this.speed = this.distance*0.00003;
  
  this.position = {
    x: x + this.distance * Math.cos(this.angle),
    y: y + this.distance * Math.sin(this.angle)
  };
  
  this.draw = function() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255," + this.opacity + ")";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }
  this.update = function() {
    this.angle += this.speed; 
    this.position = {
      x: x + this.distance * Math.cos(this.angle),
      y: y + this.distance * Math.sin(this.angle)
    };
    this.draw();
  }
}

function Emitter(x, y) {
  this.position = { x: x, y: y};
  this.radius = 30;
  this.count = 3000;
  this.particles = [];
  
  for(var i=0; i< this.count; i ++ ){
    this.particles.push(new Particle(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.radius));
  }
}


Emitter.prototype = {
  draw: function() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,1)";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();    
  },
  update: function() {  
   for(var i=0; i< this.count; i++) {
     this.particles[i].update();
   }
    this.draw(); 
  }
}


var emitter = new Emitter(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2);

function loop() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  emitter.update();
  requestAnimFrame(loop);
}

loop();
```

```css
body{background:#000;}
```

```html
 <canvas id="particle"></canvas>
```

[image]

Comment: You're updating each of 3000 points and re-drawing them once every 16 milliseconds. I would expect that to consume a lot of CPU resources.

Comment: @Pointy I agree with you but I am not able to solve this. Any help....

Comment: Solve what? You have code that explicitly performs lots and lots of computations. You might be able to do a little better by factoring out some unnecessary stuff, but all those trig functions and drawing on the canvas are going to burn CPU no matter what you do.

Comment: The code looks pretty optimal.  To reduce CPU usage, you're going to have to make a compromise.  You could either decrease the number of particles or reduce the frame rate (currently 60 frames per second or FPS).  30 FPS is generally fast enough that the human eye can't detect jitter.  Either or both should decrease CPU usage.

Comment: @BillDoughty Decreasing the number of particles to 1000 reduced the CPU usage to 50% but using 30 FPS is not making any impact. Thanks for help

Comment: Thanks for following up.  That's interesting about the 30 FPS.  That makes me think that even though the timeout is set to 16.6 ms (60 FPS) in the requestAnimFrame function, the actual rendering is taking longer, so the FPS ends up being 30 or less anyway.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Avoid semi-transparency as much as possible.

Painting with alpha is a CPU killer, avoid blending as much as possible by using solid colors:

```js
// Global Animation Setting
window.requestAnimFrame = 
  window.requestAnimationFrame ||
  window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
  window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
  window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
  window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
  function(callback) {
    window.setTimeout(callback, 1000/60);
};

// Global Canvas Setting
var canvas = document.getElementById('particle');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;


// Particles Around the Parent
function Particle(x, y, distance) {
  this.angle = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
  this.radius = Math.random() ; 
  this.opacity =  (Math.random()*5 + 2)/10;
  // convert to solid color '#nnnnnn'
  this.color = '#' + Math.floor((this.opacity * 255)).toString(16).padStart(2, 0).repeat(3);
  this.distance = (1/this.opacity)*distance;
  this.speed = this.distance*0.00003;
  
  this.position = {
    x: x + this.distance * Math.cos(this.angle),
    y: y + this.distance * Math.sin(this.angle)
  };
  
  this.draw = function() {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }
  this.update = function() {
    this.angle += this.speed; 
    this.position = {
      x: x + this.distance * Math.cos(this.angle),
      y: y + this.distance * Math.sin(this.angle)
    };
    this.draw();
  }
}

function Emitter(x, y) {
  this.position = { x: x, y: y};
  this.radius = 30;
  this.count = 3000;
  this.particles = [];
  
  for(var i=0; i< this.count; i ++ ){
    this.particles.push(new Particle(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.radius));
  }
}


Emitter.prototype = {
  draw: function() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,1)";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();    
  },
  update: function() {  
   for(var i=0; i< this.count; i++) {
     this.particles[i].update();
   }
    this.draw(); 
  }
}


var emitter = new Emitter(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2);

function loop() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  emitter.update();
  requestAnimFrame(loop);
}

loop();
```

```css
body{background:#000;}
```

```html
<canvas id="particle"></canvas>
```

But that's still not enough,

#### Avoid painting as much as possible.

The paint operations are really slow on a canvas (compared to non-paint ones) and should be avoided as much as possible. To do this, you can sort your particles by color and draw them by stack of single Path objects, but this requires that we round up a bit the `opacity` value (done when *solidifying* the color).

```js
// Global Animation Setting
window.requestAnimFrame = 
  window.requestAnimationFrame ||
  window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
  window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
  window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
  window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
  function(callback) {
    window.setTimeout(callback, 1000/60);
};

// Global Canvas Setting
var canvas = document.getElementById('particle');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;


// Particles Around the Parent
function Particle(x, y, distance) {
  this.angle = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
  this.radius = Math.random() ; 
  this.opacity =  (Math.random()*5 + 2)/10;
  // convert to solid color '#nnnnnn'
  this.color = '#' + Math.floor((this.opacity * 255)).toString(16).padStart(2, 0).repeat(3);
  this.distance = (1/this.opacity)*distance;
  this.speed = this.distance*0.00003;
  
  this.position = {
    x: x + this.distance * Math.cos(this.angle),
    y: y + this.distance * Math.sin(this.angle)
  };
  
  this.draw = function() {
    // here we remove everything but the 'arc' operation and a moveTo
    // no paint
    ctx.moveTo(this.position.x + this.radius, this.position.y);
    ctx.arc(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
  }
  this.update = function() {
    this.angle += this.speed; 
    this.position = {
      x: x + this.distance * Math.cos(this.angle),
      y: y + this.distance * Math.sin(this.angle)
    };
    // 'update' should not 'draw'
//    this.draw();
  }
}

function Emitter(x, y) {
  this.position = { x: x, y: y};
  this.radius = 30;
  this.count = 3000;
  this.particles = [];
  
  for(var i=0; i< this.count; i ++ ){
    this.particles.push(new Particle(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.radius));
  }
  // sort our particles by color (opacity = color)
  this.particles.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.opacity - b.opacity;
  });
}


Emitter.prototype = {
  draw: function() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,1)";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
    ctx.fill();
    // draw our particles in batches
    var particle, color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    for(var i=0; i<this.count; i++) {
      particle = this.particles[i];
      if(color !== particle.color) {
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = color = particle.color;
      }
      particle.draw();
    }
    ctx.fill(); // fill the last batch
    
    
  },
  update: function() {  
   for(var i=0; i< this.count; i++) {
     this.particles[i].update();
   }
    this.draw(); 
  }
}


var emitter = new Emitter(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2);

function loop() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  emitter.update();
  requestAnimFrame(loop);
}

loop();
```

```css
body{background:#000;}
```

```html
<canvas id="particle"></canvas>
```

That's better but not yet perfect...

#### Finally, be clever about YOUR animation.

In your animation, the opacity defines the distance. That is, the particles that are farther from the center are the most transparent ones. This exactly defines what a **radial gradient** is.

We can thus reduce our paint operations to two. Yes, only two paints for 3000 particles, using a radial-gradient and a bit of compositing, we can first draw **all** the particles in a single shot, and then apply the gradient as a mask which will apply its color only where there were already something painted. We can even keep the transparency.

```js
// Global Animation Setting
window.requestAnimFrame = 
  window.requestAnimationFrame ||
  window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
  window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
  window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
  window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
  function(callback) {
    window.setTimeout(callback, 1000/60);
};

// Global Canvas Setting
var canvas = document.getElementById('particle');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;


// Particles Around the Parent
function Particle(x, y, distance) {
  this.angle = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
  this.radius = Math.random() ; 
  this.opacity =  (Math.random()*5 + 2)/10;
  this.distance = (1/this.opacity)*distance;
  this.speed = this.distance*0.00003;
  
  this.position = {
    x: x + this.distance * Math.cos(this.angle),
    y: y + this.distance * Math.sin(this.angle)
  };
  
  this.draw = function() {
    // still no paint here
    ctx.moveTo(this.position.x + this.radius, this.position.y);
    ctx.arc(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
  }
  this.update = function() {
    this.angle += this.speed; 
    this.position = {
      x: x + this.distance * Math.cos(this.angle),
      y: y + this.distance * Math.sin(this.angle)
    };
    this.draw();
  }
}

function Emitter(x, y) {
  this.position = { x: x, y: y};
  this.radius = 30;
  this.count = 3000;
  this.particles = [];
  
  for(var i=0; i< this.count; i ++ ){
    this.particles.push(new Particle(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.radius));
  }
  // a radial gradient that we will use as mask
  // in particle.constructor
  // opacities go from 0.2 to 0.7
  // with a distance range of [radius, 1 / 0.2 * this.radius]
  this.grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(x, y, this.radius, x, y, 1 / 0.2 * this.radius);
  this.grad.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(255,255,255,0.7)');
  this.grad.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(255,255,255,0.2)');
}


Emitter.prototype = {
  draw: function() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,1)";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();    
  },
  update: function() {
   ctx.beginPath(); // one Path
   ctx.fillStyle = 'black'; // a solid color
   for(var i=0; i< this.count; i++) {
     this.particles[i].update();
   }
   ctx.fill(); // one paint
   // prepare the composite operation
   ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';
   ctx.fillStyle = this.grad; // our gradient
   ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height); // cover the whole canvas
   // reset for next paints (center arc and next frame's clearRect)
   ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
   this.draw(); 
  }
}

var emitter = new Emitter(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2);

function loop() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  emitter.update();
  requestAnimFrame(loop);
}

loop();
```

```css
body{background:#000;}
```

```html
<canvas id="particle"></canvas>
```