# How to make one HTML `canvas` path opaque but keep the rest transparent?

Tags: javascript

I recently started learning about drawing to the HTML canvas with javascript and made a simple game where a blackhole eats planets, with two canvas', one for the background and one for the game-play.

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="game-board"></canvas>
  <canvas id="background"></canvas>
  <script src="gameplay.js"></script>
  <script src="bg.js"></script>
</body>
```

Even though I thought I set the background color of the game-board to black...

```js
ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

...it shows as transparent, which seems strange but is actually exactly what I want.

But now I'm trying to draw a "blackhole" (just a black circle with faded edges) on top of it, but it also is always showing as transparent with regard to the other canvas, which is *not* what I want.

```js
draw() {
  let gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(
    holePosition.x,
    holePosition.y,
    holeRadius / 2,
    holePosition.x,
    holePosition.y,
    holeRadius * 2
  );
  gradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(0,0,0, 1)');
  gradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(0,0,0, 0)');
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(holePosition.x, holePosition.y, holeRadius * 2, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}
```

The blackhole correctly "blacks out" things on it's own canvas (you can see when you move it over the planets that appear), but it's still transparent with regard to the other canvas below it in the HTML showing all the stars.

So how can I make it so the blackhole also "blacks out" the other canvas behind it?

**[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-wildflower-j1fl1?file=/index.html)** (move around with arrow keys)

I've played around with `ctx.globalAlpha` and `ctx.save()`/`ctx.restore()` but with no success.

Comment: Your `#background` canvas is actually on the foreground. To clear your context use `ctx.clearRect()`, then to make your black circle, you apparently know how to make circles. Finally, to greatly improve the perfs of your white points, see [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54584214/3702797).

Comment: awesome! I guess it was in the foreground because it came last in the HTML? both switching it there and adding a negative `z-index` did what I wanted along with `clearRect()`. thanks.